# Probability on $C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, functions, stochastic-processes

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of continuous and bounded functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Is there a probability measure $p$ on $C(\mathbb{R})$ such $\forall g\in C(\mathbb{R}),\ \forall \varepsilon>0,\ p(\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}), |f-g|<\varepsilon\})>0$ ?

Comment: Also, does $|f-g|<\varepsilon$ mean  $|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, I this is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an uncounable set $\{f_\alpha\}$ with $\|f_\alpha-f_\beta\|\ge 1$ (cf. recent https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196148/non-separable-banach-space), then $A_\alpha=\{g\in C(\mathbb{R}), \|f_\alpha-g\|<1/2\}$ compose an uncountable family of disjoint sets, and thus cannot all have positive measure.